# how to call save method at the time of clicking save toolbar button in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have a doubt how to call Joomla save method using save button,and how to create new items using new button.

```
JToolBarHelper::title( 'Hello Component', 'generic.png' );
        JToolBarHelper::addNew(helloworld.add);
        JToolBarHelper::save(helloworld.save);
        JToolBarHelper::deleteList(helloworld.delete);
        JToolBarHelper::preferences('com_helloworld', '500');
```

Comment: You normally would not have these on the same toolbar. For example Save  happens when you are editing, while preferences is when you are in a manger/list view.  But what is your question?

Answer (score -2):

ToolBarHelper::title( 'your_component_view_page_title', 'generic.png' );
      JToolBarHelper::deleteList(); // Will call the task/function "remove" in your controller
      JToolBarHelper::editListX(); // Will call the task/function "edit" in your controller
      JToolBarHelper::addNewX(); // Will call the task/function "add" in your controller
      JToolBarHelper::publishList(); // Will call the task/function "publish" in your controller
      JToolBarHelper::unpublishList(); // Will call the task/function "unpublish" in your controller
      JToolBarHelper::preferences('your_component_xml_file', 'height');